# Confusion about the definition of negative angles between two D-branes

Tags: hilbert-space, string-theory, rotation, quantization, branes

I have a conceptual question regarding a [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0606001) I am reading. More precisely, the first appendix starting on page 29.

In this paper, schematically, the classical oriented open strings get quantised between two intersecting D-branes. The D-branes are rotated by the angle $\theta$ from each other.

The vacuum (for simplicity I restrict myself here to the NS and bosonic sector B) is defined as
$$
b_{r-\alpha}~\left|0\right\rangle_{\mathrm{B}} = 0~, \; \text{for} \;\; r\geq \frac{1}{2} \quad \text{and} \quad b_{r+\alpha}~\left|0\right\rangle_{\mathrm{B}} = 0~, \; \text{for} \;\; r\geq \frac{1}{2}\\
~~~a_{m-\alpha}~\left|0\right\rangle_{\mathrm{B}} = 0~, \; \text{for} \;\; r\geq 1 \quad \text{and} \quad a_{m+\alpha}~\left|0\right\rangle_{\mathrm{NS}} = 0~, \; \text{for} \;\; r\geq 0~,
$$
were $\left[0,1\right)\ni\alpha\equiv\frac{\theta}{\pi}$.

Whereas for negative angles $-1\geq \alpha \geq 0 $ we have
$$
b_{r-\alpha}~\left|0\right\rangle_{\mathrm{NS}} = 0~, \; \text{for} \;\; r\geq \frac{1}{2} \quad \text{and} \quad b_{r+\alpha}~\left|0\right\rangle_{\mathrm{NS}} = 0~, \; \text{for} \;\; r\geq \frac{1}{2}
\\
~~a_{m-\alpha}~\left|0\right\rangle_{\mathrm{B}} = 0~, \; \text{for} \;\; r\geq 0 \quad \text{and} \quad a_{m+\alpha}~\left|0\right\rangle_{\mathrm{B}} = 0~, \; \text{for} \;\; r\geq 1~.
$$

In addition, depending on the definition and the choice of the angle, physical quantities can be determined in a standard way. For example, for the choice of a positive angle we get a zero point energy
$$
\epsilon_0=-\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{2}\alpha~.
$$
For a negative angle $\epsilon_0$ reads
$$
\epsilon_0=-\frac{1}{8}-\frac{1}{2}\alpha~.
$$
Here it is important to note that the angle has a *negative* domain.

**Question**: Now in this paper (p.32) – as well as in other papers – it is said that *negative* angles can be expressed by *positive* angles. This is given by:
$$
\alpha \rightarrow \alpha'=1+\alpha.
$$
This fact confuses me however, since normally a negative angle changes its orientation by $2\pi$ and not $\pi$. What does it graphically mean?

Physically, it should be said that the choice of the angle - whether positive or negative - determines whether the oriented string corresponds to a particle or anti-particle.